# Unable to check for valid Login from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to check for valid Username from SQLite on Android but I am getting this error:

```
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477): Process: com.example.easycontacts, PID: 9477
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.example.easycontacts.DatabaseConnector.checkLogin(DatabaseConnector.java:50)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.example.easycontacts.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-02 00:35:41.885: E/AndroidRuntime(9477):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Here's my `MainActivity` file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        signUp();
        login();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void login() {
        final Context context = this;
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        final String strUsername = username.getText().toString();
        final String strPassword = password.getText().toString();

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector(context);
                // if (db.getSingleEntry(strUsername, strPassword)) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // }
                String storedPassword = db.checkLogin(strUsername);
                Log.d("",storedPassword);
                if (storedPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(strPassword)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        });
    }

    public void signUp() {
        final Context context = this;
        Button signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Signup.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

and `DatabaseConnector`:

```
public class DatabaseConnector {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Login";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        databaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME,
                null, 3);

    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = databaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() throws SQLException {
        database.close();
    }

    public void registerUser(String username, String password) {
        ContentValues newUser = new ContentValues();
        newUser.put("username", username);
        newUser.put("password", password);
        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        database.insert("users", null, newUser);
        try {
            close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public String checkLogin(String username) {
        Cursor cursor = database.query("users", null, "username=" + username,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;

    }
}
```

and `DatabaseOpenHelper`:

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE users"
                + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + "username TEXT, password TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(createQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

What I might be doing wrong? I am pretty sure, I am doing wrong somewhere in DatabaseConnector file.

There's one more thing, I can insert into the Database perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your checkLogin() method with following

```
public String checkLogin(String username)
{
    Cursor cursor = database.query("users", null,  "username"+ "='" + username.trim() + "'",
                null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) return "";
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));  
    return password;
}
```

Replace your loginButton method with following

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector(context);
            db.open();
            String storedPassword = db.checkLogin(strUsername);
            db.close();

            if (storedPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(strPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    });
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: have you received a correct password in your query?? please put a debug point on checklogin() method.

Comment: It stops at this, `Cursor cursor = database.query("users", null, "username" + "='"
    + username + "'", null, null, null, null);`

Comment: your case is also weird, once you said it always get success then u said it stops on above line now you are saying it isn't show any error?? you say in this case how one can help you??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42300/discussion-between-andrain-and-user1601973)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the `password` field from the table and in your query you have not even requested for that column that is why you are getting the error.

Try to get the result using the `rawQuery` as below:

```
Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE TRIM(username) = '"+username.trim()+"'", null);

   if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
  {
     //  to get data
     cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
     {
       //  do get data from cursor
       String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
    }

    return password;
}
```

Comment: The method is `size()` is undefined for type cursor.

Comment: Try out with `getCount()`.

Comment: Where should I place `return password`?

Comment: It still says this, `This method must return a result of type String`

Comment: Check out i have updated my answer by writing the return statement after while loop.

Comment: Try out your if loop like `if (strPassword.equalsIgnoreCase(storedPassword)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: Also check for the null values for your password strings.

Answer (score 0):

When you call for check login. This is the code

```
 DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector(context);
                // if (db.getSingleEntry(strUsername, strPassword)) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // }
                String storedPassword = db.checkLogin(strUsername);
```

But the thing is, at that time your DatabaseConnector class, your

```
  private SQLiteDatabase database;
```

is not instantiated.

So the in chekLogin(), the database object is null.

Try this.

```
 DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector(context);
                    // if (db.getSingleEntry(strUsername, strPassword)) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success!",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // }
                    db.open();
                    String storedPassword = db.checkLogin(strUsername);
                    db.close();
```

I hope this would work.